# Smooth parameterized surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

$S\subseteq R^3$ a smooth parameterized surface.

1.1.:) The area of a surface is invariant under euclidean movement. If $y=Ax+b$ is an euclidean movement in $R^3$ ($A\in R_{n\times n}$ is orthogonal and $b\in R^n$ is arbitrary), show that

$A(S')=A(S)$

for $S':=${$Ax+b|x\in S$}.

1.2.:) For $\lambda \neq 0$ let $\lambda \cdot S:=${$\lambda \cdot x|x\in S$}. Show that $A(S')=\lambda^2A(S)$.

I've started learning for my exam, which is in a couple of weeks from now. I started off by doing the exercises given in my textbook and I've been struggling on this one for a few hours now. We have never dealt with problems such as these in class so I have no method of solving it yet. I would appreciate it if someone had hints on how to approach this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write down the definition of Area. It should be something like 
$$\int_S ??? \ dx  dy.$$

For (1), show that that $???$ is the same, and for (2), show that the new $???$ is $\lambda^2$ times that of the old one.

Comment: I can't seem to find the formula in my textbook. The only thing I found was $\int_Sf(x,y)d(x,y)=\int_Idx\int_Jdyf(x,y)$.

Comment: How do your textbook define area then? (What's your textbook?) @Rab

Comment: It's a german textbook. But I think I found a better one. Is this correct?:
${\int\int}_S \rho d\sigma :=\int_I \rho(F(u,v))\|F_u(u,v)\times F_v(u,v)\|d^2(u,v)$ and $S:X=F(u,v), ~~(u,v)\in I$.

Comment: This is the definition of a integral of the function $\rho$. So in our case, we calculate $\int\int_S d\sigma $ (that is, $\rho =  1$).@Rab

Answer (score 0):

**Alternatively:** I prefer to look at area as second Hausdorff measure what is more clear, than it is quite obvius in $1.1$ because diameter is unvariant under translations and in second - $1.2$ also because scaling, scale the diameter.